# I cannot process the following for loop to calculate count() from Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop

My raw data frame has 2 Columns : 'Name of State' & 'Name of City'.

I'm trying to prepare a List that stores 'Name of State' , 'Name of City' and the count of how many times does that city name appears ; later on I will convert this list to a Data Frame.

But apparently the code does not work.

```
lst = []
for sname in data['State'].unique():
    temp = data[data['State']==sname]
    for cname in temp['City'].unique():
        lst.append([sname,cname,data['City'].count(cname)])
```

[This is My Data and Present Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5nI7.png)

Comment: Use value_counts `data['City'].value_counts()` or groupby `df.groupby(['State', 'City'])['City'].transform('count')`?

Comment: @iSiddharthKekre add the expected output

Comment: Also, never add data as image. Paste data as text from jupyter.